# Cordova build failed (phonegap)

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

In my app i want to add google plus login. I am following [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)
github project. After that I add `<gap:plugin>` tag in config.xml but after this when i try to build app for android platform by using `cordova build` command it gives me an error. Error snapshot given below.
[image: Build error]

I have two questions related to this question. 
Question1: When we create app using cordova by `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` then many config.xml files created.
First in= Hello--> config.xml

Second in= hello-->platforms-->android-->res-->xml-->config.xml
So in which `config.xml` I need to add `<gap:plugin>` tag?

 I am adding tag like this.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm">
  <param name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="myreversedclientid" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Question2: Why is this error occurred when i try to build app using `cordova build` command? (This error only occurred when i include `gap:plugin` tag in config.xml) (position of xml-->Hello--> config.xml) (for error look at error snapshot).

Here is my config.xml file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm">
  <param name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="myreversedclientid" />
</gap:plugin>
</widget>
```

Comment: post your config.xml

Comment: @sunil sunil I added config.xml in my question

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add the plugin manually, you can just do

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
```

This should add the plugin. To check your installed plugins, do

```
cordova plugin list
```

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus  in this link at point 5 they said in need to add plugin tag in config.xml after installation of app????

Comment: That's if you're using phonegap(now cordova) which you're not. You might want to read a bit about the history of phonegap and cordova to get an idea of what's what.

Answer (score 0):

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus" version="1.0.7" />
```

include only this line into your config.xml for adding google+ plugin.

You will find all plugin information for Phonegap [Plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) here.
google+ is third party plugin for phonegap, so I will recommend you to read API for plugin first. You will find details at given link for plugins.

And you need to add plugins into your root config.xml which you posted. No need to add it to platform config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check if you also installed the "Google Repository".[sample load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zNjy.png)